# Adding a bend to a straight connector in Microsoft Visio 2013

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I have added a straight connector:

[image]

how can I add to some bends to obtain the following result

[image]

?

I use Microsoft Visio 2013 Professional on Windows 7.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### How can I add to some bends?

> 1. Click the "Pointer Tool" on the toolbar and highlight the connector line.
> 2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and drag the mid-point handle of the connector line up or down.
>
>    This will add corners at 90 degree angles to the line with control
>      handles that can be used to manipulate the line further.
>
> **Tips & Warnings**
>
> - To add corners at angles less than 90 degrees, press <kbd>control</kbd> while moving the midpoint of the connector line up
>     or down.
> - To convert a straight line connector to a curved line, right-click on the connector and select "Curved Connector."

Source [How to Add Corners to Visio Connectors](http://www.ehow.com/how_7407869_add-corners-visio-connectors.html)

Comment: Thanks, looks like we found the solution at the same time.

Comment: Yes. You posted 5 seconds before I finished my answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution on http://packetlife.net/blog/2012/apr/11/drawing-continuous-connectors-visio/ :

> A connector can be manipulated so that it spawns additional angles by
>   **holding the shift or control key** while dragging its midpoint. Holding
>   the shift key will break out the middle of the line, creating four new
>   right angles (the first example below). Holding the control key will
>   create a single angle of an arbitrary degree at the midpoint (the
>   second example below).
>
> [image]

Once you have created new midpoint, you can either move the midpoint or the corner, by first selecting the connector:

[image]

[image]

The midpoints and corners marked with a slightly darker blue that is almost invisible:

[image]

Comment: I still had some doubts after reading the 'best-answer', but your diagrams cleared 'em right up! Awesome work, mate!